# connect to Devops boards using odata in R

Tags: r, api, odata, devops

I'm trying to extract work items data from Devops boards through odata in R, so I can do some analysis on our work items.

I can do this in excel, but when I try in R I get a 401 error. I am using a PAT, which is correct, as I copied it from my R script into excel, as I did with the url.

This is my R code:

```
url <- https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/{version}

username <- "test"
```

password is my PAT that has read permission on Analytics

```
MyData <- httr::GET(url, authenticate("username", "password"))
```

This should return all tables, but instead I get a list with

```
 MyData$status_code = 401
```

Comment: My bad. I removed the quotation marks from username and password but now get a 200 error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.